How to optimize this simple network for VNC remote control?
Equipment:

Router: TP-Link TL-WR741ND
Two Windows 11/10 Laptops

Connectors for PC1: 100 meters long CAT5 UTP straight through.
Connectors for PC2: 2 meters long CAT5 UTP straight through.



In a venue we have two screens. They are 100 meters apart from each other. I cannot afford HDMI to Ethernet converters. Thats why I turned to this solution of connecting them through VNC protocol.
I have Two PCs. I have connected them with a TP-link router in the middle. The main object here is to synchronize this PCs' screens and control one of them from another.
I am using TightVNC for remote control.
Everything is fine except one issue. Video playback is very-very laggy on one PC.
Question: What optimizations are possible on this network? You can advise me for change of protocol (I have tried Windows Remote Desktop but one PC logs off and only one   can show the desktop on this option). For example what optimizations are possible on VNC protocol? What optimizations are possible in router configurations?

you won't find network optimizations do much of anything for VNC, unless you have a very cheap switch, in which case replacing it would be indicated. VNC will probably never perform for you as well as you'd like it to for remote video playback.

Just in case someone looking for a fast way of remote controlling another PC on a local network, I ended up using free software NoMachine which uses NX protocol.
It provides much better refresh rate and can easily be installed on different platforms.
